# Rename the filename in build.gradle with version

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am working on one gradle script where I need to rename the artifact name at the end but I am facing an issue my code is below.Version is coming from the 
version.properties file and I am able to read it properly in build.gradle script but while I change the name of the artifact at the end for e.g. libmain.so to NativeJNI-4.0.0_15 then it doesn't change and change it from libmain.so to filechange.Cansome one let me know what is the issue here

```
    def filechange = file("NativeJNI-${project.version}.so")
    //println filechange
    task fixartifactname (type: Copy) {
           //def filechange = "NativeJNI-${project.version}.so"
           //println filechange
           from 'build/binaries/mainSharedLibrary'
           into 'build/libs'
   // def filechange = file("NativeJNI-${project.version}.so")
    println filechange
    include('libmain.so')
    rename ('libmain.so', '${filechange}')
    }
    //println fixartifactname
    build.dependsOn fixartifactname
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix my issue in below way

```
def filechange = file("build/libs/NativeJNI-${project.version}.so")
task copyfile(type: Copy) {
     from 'build/binaries/mainSharedLibrary'
     into 'build/libs'
     include('libmain.so')
     rename ('libmain.so', filechange.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per your question I understand that you're building a native binary. Did you try to set the `baseName` property for your component? This way you could create your shared library with your desired name from the first place.

Now, regarding your code above then it contains 2 problems:

1. When calling `rename` you're wrapping `${filechange}` with a single apostrophe (`'`) rather than using inverted commas(`"`), thus this variable is not being resolved to its value. Also, there is no need for a closure block here.
2. By default using `filechange` inside the rename would map to its string value which is its full path rather than just the new file name. To overcome this simply use the `name` property of `filechange`.

To conclude, each of the following options should do the work for you:

```
// use inverted commas
rename ('libmain.so', "$filechange.name")

// remove apostrophe or commas
rename ('libmain.so', filechange.name) //

// groovy style function call with no paranthesis
rename 'libmain.so', filechange.name //
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to fix my issue